# Why does javax.lang.model.element.Name exist?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Is there any value in using the [`javax.lang.model.element.Name` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Name.html) instead of immediately calling `toString()` on it?

Comment: Telling by the question, I am not sure you are using it right at all.

Comment: Types like `Name` are, in compiler design, often pre-interned for efficiency.  Calling `toString` may incur a performance penalty, which may or may not matter to you.

Comment: It shows it's a value indicating the name of some element, as opposed to any other random string.